# Java Security Risks for using URL class to get html source

Tags: java, url

Hello I have a question about the `java.net.URL` class.
If I just type a random url, and get the `html` in string form, do I put my computer at risk?

Is it possible that a certain website maybe exploits the `URL` class and take over my computer though my application, or at least infects with some kind of malware.

I hope that my question is clear, if not please ask me to clear it up, English is not my native language.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: As you request the contents through HTTP, how should anyone know that you're using Java as a backing technology and not Python or C# or anything else?

Comment: @Smutje To know if there is Java as backing technology used on a certain computer is irrelevant to the attacker as long as there is a sufficient chance that there are at least some victims using Java as backing technology.

Answer (score 1):

> If I just type a random url, and get the html in string form, do I put my computer at risk?

You do not specify what you would consider to be a *risk*. But fetching a string consumes network bandwidth, CPU time and (in most cases) storage space for the down-loaded text. A malicious HTTP server than served an infinite random string would use some of your network bandwidth and CPU forever, and if your program stored the string would eventually cause your program to fail with an `OutOfMemoryError`. If your program was configured to use a large fraction of the RAM of the computer, the URL would reduce the performance of *all the other programs* on your computer, until your program exited.

Something similar, a [tarpit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_%28networking%29), has been done to slow down malicious programs, such as computer worms.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way by which any string can harm your machine. There is no harm until and unless you try to execute some extract from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Getting it in string form in itself won't do any harm, although if you set no timeout and don't do the fetching in a background thread, it is possible for the remote party to "freeze" your application by intentionally sending data incredibly slowly.

All this can be avoided by using `Executor`s to fetch the html and setting a sensible limit to how long you're willing to wait for the content.

There is also the buffer size problem that [Raedwald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/545127/raedwald) mentions, again this can be avoided by limiting the amount of data you accept.

Remember though that while getting the content into a string is safe (with the caveats mentioned already), what you then do with that string is what can make things dangerous.